# proper argument to extend logical volume, /dev/mapper/vg-lv or /dev/vg/lv?

Tags: linux, partition, lvm

I'm bit new in Linux and Please don't be too hard on me :)

I'm adding new disk to LVM group and bit on confused on last stage:

Disk structure:

```
# lvs
  LV   VG Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  root cl -wi-ao----   1.70g
  swap cl -wi-ao---- 308.00m
# vgs
  VG #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize VFree
  cl   2   2   0 wz--n- 6.99g 5.00g
# pvs
  PV         VG Fmt  Attr PSize PFree
  /dev/sda2  cl lvm2 a--  2.00g    0
  /dev/sdc1  cl lvm2 a--  5.00g 5.00g
```

From lvdisplay

```
  LV Path                /dev/cl/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                cl
```

Now this is the partition I need to extend:

```
# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/mapper/cl-root: 1820 MB, 1820327936 bytes, 3555328 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

and df output

```
# df -H
Filesystem           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/cl-root  1.9G  1.8G   90M  96% /
devtmpfs             237M     0  237M   0% /dev
tmpfs                248M     0  248M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                248M  4.8M  243M   2% /run
tmpfs                248M     0  248M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1            1.1G  240M  824M  23% /boot
tmpfs                 50M     0   50M   0% /run/user/0
```

Now Question is, The extend command should look like this ? :

```
lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/cl-root
```

or like this ? :

```
lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/cl/root
```

Comment: Get the precise name from `lvs` command. And maybe you would like to keep some diskspace unallocated...

Comment: It is normally the lvpath and so /dev/cl/root

Comment: I would expect both to work, latter case may be more common in non linux (HP-UX for instance). I would advise against using `/dev/sdc1` as physical volume, since you use LVM, format `/dev/sdc` as physical volume. (this way it can be enlarged)

Comment: Either of these is fine.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/sdc to extend Logical Volume on top of the Volume Group ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of the options you asked about are identical. Either one will work.

`/dev/mapper/c1-root` and `/dev/c1/root` are both symbolic links to a device mapper in `/dev/`, such as `/dev/dm-1`, for example.

Do **NOT** run `lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/sdc`. `lvextend` is expecting a logical volume, not a partition.

Also, you shouldn't use `fdisk` on logical volumes. `fdisk` is meant for real block devices not the virtual block devices created by device mapper.